# x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ fails to compile, g++ works fine

Tags: c++, linux, g++, mingw32

I'm trying to cross-compile a program for windows on linux, but the mingw32 compiler is getting errors that aren't present with g++.

the command:

```
g++ *.cpp -o game -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -lftgl -lopenal -lalut -I/usr/include/freetype2
```

compiles the program perfectly fine.  However the mingw32 equivalent (as far as I can tell) outputs the following errors:

```
    /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ *.cpp -o game.exe -I /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -L /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lGL -lglu -lglut -lglfw -lfreetype -lftgl -lopenal -lalut -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/freetype2

    In file included from gesplit.cpp:22:0:
text.h:14:45: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
       TEXT(string,int=12,int=0,int=0,int=0,int=0);
                                             ^
    text.h:15:52: error: macro "TEXT" passed 7 arguments, but takes just 1
       TEXT(WORLD&,string,int=12,int=0,int=0,int=0,int=0);
                                                    ^
    gesplit.cpp:85:102: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
     back(new TEXT("PRESS ENTER TO START",24,(screen.w/2)-250,(screen.h-24)/4,0,0));
                                                                                 ^
    gesplit.cpp:86:98: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
         ush_back(new TEXT("WASD - ARROW KEYS:     MOVE",12,40,(screen.h-24)/2+20,0,0));
                                                                             ^
    gesplit.cpp:87:96: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
     .push_back(new TEXT("P:                     PAUSE",12,40,(screen.h-24)/2,0,0));
                                                                               ^
    gesplit.cpp:88:99: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
     sh_back(new TEXT("SPACE:                 SHOOT",12,40,(screen.h-24)/2-20,0,0));
                                                                             ^
    gesplit.cpp:89:118: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
     SC:                   QUIT GAME LIKE A QUITTER",12,40,(screen.h-24)/2-40,0,0));
                                                                             ^ 
    gesplit.cpp:90:98: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
     ush_back(new TEXT("SPACE SHOOT",40,(screen.w/2)-220,(screen.h-24)*3/4+20,0,0));
                                                                             ^
    gesplit.cpp:91:94: error: macro "TEXT" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
     xt.push_back(new TEXT("ZAP-ZAP",40,(screen.w/2)-140,(screen.h-24)*3/4-20,0,0));
                                                                             ^
    gesplit.cpp:96:100: error: macro "TEXT" passed 7 arguments, but takes     just 1
     (new TEXT(new_world,("SCORE "+intToString(globalScore)),24,0,screen.h-24,0,0));
                                                                                 ^
    In file included from gesplit.cpp:22:0:
    text.h:14:3: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
       TEXT(string,int=12,int=0,int=0,int=0,int=0);
        ^
    text.h:15:3: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
       TEXT(WORLD&,string,int=12,int=0,int=0,int=0,int=0);
       ^
    gesplit.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    gesplit.cpp:62:64: error: no matching function for call to       ‘TEXT::TEXT(const char [6], int, int, int, int, int)’
       TEXT pauseText("PAUSE",24,(screen.w/2)-62,(screen.h-24)/2,0,0);
                                                                ^
    In file included from gesplit.cpp:22:0:
    text.h:8:7: note: candidate: TEXT::TEXT()
     class TEXT:public OBJECT
       ^
    text.h:8:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 6 provided
    text.h:8:7: note: candidate: TEXT::TEXT(const TEXT&)
    text.h:8:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 6 provided
```

It looks to me that mingw32 doesn't like the copy constructor where the TEXT class is using OBJECT's constructor.  I have several classes that use the same format and don't raise errors.  It might be a problem with ftgl.h, because TEXT is the only class that uses it, but this looks too much like a syntax error.

text.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/gl.h>
//#include <freetype2/freetype/config/ftheader.h>
//#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
#include <FTGL/ftgl.h>
#include <FTGL/FTGLPixmapFont.h>
#include "person.h"
#include "object.h"
#include "world.h"
#include "text.h"
#include "coord.h"
#include "globals.h"
using namespace std;

TEXT::TEXT(WORLD& world_a,string text_a,int size_a,int x_a,int y_a,int     xvel_a,int yvel_a)
  :OBJECT(world_a,x_a,y_a,xvel_a,yvel_a)
{
  type="TEXT";
  layer=6;
  cout<<"begin text constructor"<<endl;
  text=text_a;
  cout<<"set text"<<endl;
  font = new FTPixmapFont("emulogic.ttf");
  cout<<"set font"<<endl;
  font->FaceSize(size_a);
  cout<<"end text constructor"<<endl;
}

TEXT::TEXT(string text_a,int size_a,int x_a,int y_a,int xvel_a,int yvel_a)
  :OBJECT(x_a,y_a,xvel_a,yvel_a)
{
  type="TEXT";
  layer=6;
  cout<<"begin text constructor"<<endl;
  text=text_a;
  cout<<"set text"<<endl;
  font = new FTPixmapFont("emulogic.ttf");
  cout<<"set font"<<endl;
  font->FaceSize(size_a);
  cout<<"end text constructor"<<endl;
}

void TEXT::render()
{
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(x,y,0);

  glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  /*glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.3f);
  glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  glVertex3f(screen.w,0.0f,0.0f);
  glVertex3f(screen.w,32.0f,0.0f);
  glVertex3f(0.0f,32.0f,0.0f);
  glEnd();
  */

  glColor4d(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
  font->Render(text.c_str(),-1,FTPoint(x,y,0)); //text doesn't transform, so use FTPoint
  glPopAttrib();
  glPopMatrix();
}

bool TEXT::logic(int step)
{
  switch(step)
    {
    case 0:
      break;
    default:
      return true;
      break;
    }
  return false; 
}

void TEXT::setText(string text_a)
{
  text=text_a;
}

void TEXT::setFontSize(int size)
{
  font->FaceSize(size);
}
```

any/all help is appreciated.

Comment: "macro "TEXT"", hint, hint. Looks like some header you included defined it as a macro (IIRC Windows headers do that). Rename your class - ALLCAPS should be limited to macros anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, TEXT is a macro function that tells the compiler to use the string passed to it as UTF-16 when UNICODE is defined, and as an ANSI string otherwise. Since the preprocessor is executed before the actual compilation, it knows nothing of the class you defined. It thinks you are making a call to the macro function, which accepts just one argument. This is why it's giving you the error. Rename your class to solve the problem.

Comment: Another option is `#undef TEXT`, although in the interest of interacting with other Windows code, renaming the class is a better solution IMO.